# CRM plugin execution of operations before Exception

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a plugin that needs to create a bunch of entities, and does so using;

```
service.Create(Entity);
```

At the end of the plugin (pre-operation on Update, synchronous) I sometimes need to cancel the save operation. The only way I know how is to throw an exception, but if I do that my service.Create(Entity) does not get executed.

How do I force the service to execute the operations inside the plugin, and then cancel the save by throwing an exception?

EDIT:  The code is;

```
var id = service.Create(newEntity);
throw new Exception("Cancelled Save but created the new entity");
```

If I throw the exception, the entity does not get created. If I do not throw the exception, the entity does create. I need it to create and also throw the exception so that the save operation is cancelled.

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Are you trying to perform validations before updating the entity and if the validations fail, writing to an error table (new entity) with your `service.Create(Entity)` and also informing the user that the update operation failed with the message?

Comment: Essentially I am creating a custom entity which logs details about what the user tried to change, and then disallowing the save. I am doing this in a plugin because there may be workflows and / or other services trying to modify the record.

Comment: If `IPluginExecutionContext.IsInTransaction == true` then if you throw an Exception anything that you've done will be rolled back. Btw, not sure what you mean by your comment - but the plugin can still fire if a workflow updates the record. You can try registering in the Pre-Validation stage and sometimes that is outside the transaction, but not always. It appears to me that the solution architecture for your implementation is inconsistent with the Dynamics CRM platform.

Comment: I registered in the Pre-Validation stage and this achieves what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: Just be aware that there is no guarantee it'll always be outside of the transaction. The SDK documents make this very clear - so at anytime an update could occur that puts it in a transaction.

Comment: @Nicknow.  True, but rather vague (of them)!  I would hope it's deterministic rather than random.   It seems likely that (within-transaction) plugin code that triggers other plugins to fire would cause pre-validate to be included in the existing transaction.    Just musing....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nicknow's answer is correct, but there are still a few ways to accomplish what you want to do.

1. In your plugin, don't use the OrganizationService from the plugin context. Create your own new OrganizationService just like you would if you were creating a console app. This new OrganizationService won't be subject to the transaction scope of the original OrganizationService.
2. Create a web service that does the work. From your plugin, call this web service. The web service won't be subject to the transaction scope of the original OrganizationService.
3. Use ExecuteMultiple. I've never tried this but here's somebody who claims it works: http://crmtidbits.blogspot.com/2014/02/bypass-plug-in-transaction-to-log.html

Hope that helps!

Comment: It depends the crm version and rollup

Comment: @Sxntk Are you saying the Execute Multiple trick only works in certain instances of CRM?

Comment: @Daryl "... ExecuteMultipleRequest has been added to the Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 Update Rollup 12..." Here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj863631%28v=crm.5%29.aspx

Comment: @Sxntk You made it sound like ExecuteMultiple only executes in its own transaction in certain versions of CRM.  What you mean is that the ExecuteMultiple is only available in 2011 UR 12  and newer as well as online?

Comment: @Daryl Oh no, sorry, yeah, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

If `IPluginExecutionContext.IsInTransaction == true` then when an Exception is thrown anything that has been written to the database will be rolled back. You can try registering in the Pre-Validation stage and sometimes that is outside the transaction, but not always.

Just be aware that there is no guarantee it'll always be outside of the transaction. The SDK documents make this very clear - so at anytime an update could occur that puts it in a transaction.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327941.aspx#bkmk_DatabaseTransactions:

> Plug-ins may or may not execute within the database transaction of the
>   Microsoft Dynamics CRM platform. Whether a plug-in is part of the
>   transaction is dependent on how the message request is processed by
>   the pipeline. You can check if the plug-in is executing in-transaction
>   by reading the IsInTransaction property inherited by
>   IPluginExecutionContext that is passed to the plug-in. If a plug-in is
>   executing in the database transaction and allows an exception to be
>   passed back to the platform, the entire transaction will be rolled
>   back. Stages 20 and 40 are guaranteed to be part of the database
>   transaction while stage 10 may be part of the transaction.
>
> Any registered plug-in that executes during the database transaction
>   and that passes an exception back to the platform cancels the core
>   operation. This results in a rollback of the core operation. In
>   addition, any pre-event or post event registered plug-ins that have
>   not yet executed and any workflow that is triggered by the same event
>   that the plug-in was registered for will not execute.

Comment: So to be clear, there is no way I can guarantee that my plugin executes outside of a transaction? My requirement is to perform operations using service.Create(entity) and then cancel the Save operation that is taking place.

Comment: What you are doing is the closest you can get but you can't guarantee it. That may or may not matter depending on your use case. If you absolutely must guarantee it you'll need to make a call out from the plugin to an external system and have that external system save the data to CRM or another datastore.

Comment: "...Pre-Validation stage and sometimes that is outside the transaction, but not always." Pre-Validation is **ALWAYS** outside the transaction, except when a Pre or Post Operaration plug-in calls it.

Comment: @Sxntk - That is making an assumption that is NOT documented in the SDK, therefore while it works right now there is no commitment from the product team that it will continue working that way. In a rollup they could decide to put all stage 10 plugin executions inside the transaction. As my previous comment made clear, yes this works today but you are not guaranteed it will always work and you've been told to NOT rely on it always working.

Comment: @Nicknow Certainly we are clear this is not a best practice, and Josh Painter answer has a better aproach. But that's why is needs to be clear, pre-validation will not rollback and that's why you shouldn't register transaction plug-ins in that message, always prefer pre-operation.

Comment: a question: if updates are made in the pre-validation stage of a plugin, and an error occurs in the pre-execution or post stage of another plugin of same event, what will be the effect on the updates made in the pre-validation stage? Will the updates be rolled back automatically (that are made in the pre-validation stage) or stored in memory and not yet committed to the database?